# How to close Forticlient on OS X without admin password

Tags: macos, vpn

I'm using Forticlient (v5.2.5.383) on OS X, and every time I quit the application it asks for my admin password in order to close. I've never seen such behavior from any other application — including other VPN software.  Inputting a root password all the time as the standard operating procedure for using a VPN client is not exactly best security practice.

Why does Forticlient want an admin password in order to quit? And more importantly, how can you disable this behavior?

I haven't noticed any issues after simply killing the process, which does not require root privileges.  Perhaps that's the best workaround, but I wonder if there is a good reason Forticlient wants root privilege or a better way of disabling it.

Comment: 2.5 years later and I'm still wondering that.

Comment: 6.5 years later and I'm still wondering how such a stupid behavior could be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have the source and you're willing to rebuild it... Yeah, forcing it is probably the simplest way haha. Maybe you can write a unix script to kill it and make it an executable, and run it from the dock. This would be a nice way to open it too :)